# Install FFMPEG on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg

I am trying to install FFMPEG to work with my NodeJs server. 
I am using `heroku-buildpack-multi` plugin:
`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`

I have created a `.buildpacks` (without extesion) file at my github repository. This is what it includes:

`https://github.com/jayzes/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg`
`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodej`

Each time i am trying to push my changes to heroku, this is what i get:

`-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... failed
 !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack`

Unforlunatly, there is not much information regarding ffmpeg installtion
on heroku. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tried this with a demo app I cloned from Heroku:

https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git

I was able to deploy successfully following the same steps you listed above, except I added an 's' to the end of your second buildpack (you have a typo - could this be the issue?): `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs`

I would recommend following the same process with a fresh codebase to help troubleshoot your environment. But note two things: 1) The heroku-buildpack-multi plugin you're using is deprecated, and 2) Heroku officially supports multiple buildpacks:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

and has an officially supported ffmpeg buidback you can use:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest