# Joining a voice channel on ready (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried this:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  let channel = client.channels.get('432462518380789771');
  channel.join()
});
```

It doesnt work. I made sure that the ID is right and everything and its still not working.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Im not sure how to see the errors... Im using heroku to host my discord bot.

Comment: Well but while in development, why are you hosting the bot on a remote machine?

Comment: umm... i tried downloading the code and running it locally but its all messed up and gives a lot of errors

Comment: And those errors are?

Comment: okay i just figured out how to see the console and these are the errors im getting: https://pastebin.com/raw/bS6VMM1S (link to pastebin cuz too long)

Comment: if you using discord.js v13, this might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785098/10471503

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering we have no context on the error you're receiving, I'll provide a code example to see if this fixes your issue.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.get("mychannelid");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    // Yay, it worked!
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

In this code, we use the ready event and then get the channel, like you do. In addition, we also check if the channel is undefined or null, meaning the bot was unable to find the channel or did not have it cached. Then, we join and see if we get a returning connection. If we do, log to the console the fact we successfully connected. If it didn't successfully connect, we'll catch it and error it to console.

It's always a good idea when debugging to include logging to see how far your code runs, and to see where issues may occur. In Node.js, it's also a good idea to catch for unhandledRejections. Otherwise, they will crash your process. You can do that via the code example below.

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", console.error);
```

Good luck, and happy coding!

EDIT: With the new information, I now very easily see the issue. Notice how in the error it says:

```
Error: FFMPEG not found
```

You can see that you do not currently have FFMPEG installed. To install FFMPEG, go to [this url](https://www.ffmpeg.org) to download the sources for your platform. Check out [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows) to see how to install it on Windows.

Comment: im not sure how to see the console on heroku. is it possible to print the error in a text channel for example: message.channel.send(e); or something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with heroku. If you run it using `node myapp`, then it should just log to where you ran that command. Otherwise, googling "how to see logs on heroku" may be helpful.

Comment: How can i install it to work with the code that i have on github. The heroku app pulls code from github.

Comment: You have to install it on every device you clone your GitHub to

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011619/install-ffmpeg-on-heroku).

Comment: In specific, it links [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest), if that makes sense to you.

Comment: erm... so i created a file called .buildpacks and added the link as instructed. the app was deploying a little longer then normal. it didnt connect tho and only this is on my console: https://pastebin.com/raw/UFaWqCWn

Comment: i added the line to .buildpacks and i still get this error: https://pastebin.com/raw/u5vSeD7N

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with heroku so I've provided the maximum amount of support I can. I apologize.

Comment: Oh, there is a section in options called buildpacks and i added it there and it installed i could see in the logs and its working! The bot is connected to the channel! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This would be an updated version for the working code for update v12.
As of 02/05/2020.

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelIDhere");
    if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        // Yay, it worked!
        console.log("Successfully connected.");
    }).catch(e => {

        // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
        console.error(e);
    });
});
```