# Making Discord Bot join/leave a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I edited the question with new code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

I want my bot to join a channel when it starts up or by command
anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean "join a channel"? Do you mean a voice channel? Do you mean a server? Bots can't "join" text channels because when you join a server you're already in every text channel? Please be more specific.

Comment: You seem to be asking people to code a bot for you, this is not how stack works, in future please ask a question that does not ask for code, but for a point in the right direction or a correction of an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code will join the voice channel - change ‘mychannelid’ to your desired voice channel’s id.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.get("mychannelid");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

Credit for this code goes to user @FireController1847
In this [Joining a voice channel on ready (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844393/joining-a-voice-channel-on-ready-discord-js) thread