# Error when joining voice channel: channel.join is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("750063752149205222");
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("757004209701912587");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

making bot join VC gives error, If you have a fix for it that would be amazing!

Comment: It'd be useful if you could mention the error. Thanks!

Comment: As stated in the title: "channel.join is not a function"

Comment: Try using console.log(channel) right before your channel.join function. Then, add the output to your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining a voice channel on ready (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844393/joining-a-voice-channel-on-ready-discord-js)

Comment: Since `channel` is not undefined, your code has definitely found a channel. However, given that `.join()` is not a property of the channel that has been found, this indicates that the channel that was retrieved is not a voice channel. Your bot is trying to "join" a text channel or category, not a voice channel, hence the error. The ID you are using to retrieve your channel is probably incorrect.