# How do I set a variable to a specific voice channel discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to set a `variable` to a specific `voice channel` so that I can always have the bot work in the **same** channel rather than whatever channel the user is in. I'm new to js and writing discord bots. Most of my code is from [here](https://www.gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot).

So far I've tried everything I can think of from

```
  const voiceChannel = channel_ID;
```

to

```
  const voiceChannel = channel.id(channel_ID);
```

(Where channel_ID is the actual ID number discord assigns)

I've looked on discord.js.org but I can't find a solution.

I'm probably doing something incredibly obvious wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: So do you want a `variable` containing just the `ID` or the actual [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) `object`?

Comment: I guess using the GuildChannel object? I'm trying to get it to a point where I can basically just use voiceChannel.join() and have it join the specified voice channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to `join` your bot on a specific `channel` you first have to actually get  the `channel`

### How to get the (`ID` of your) `channel`?

Well, you have two options for this:

- Activate the `developer mode` in your `Discord` > Right-click on the `target channel` and select `Copy ID` > paste it into your code

```js
const channelId = '1234567890';
const targetChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
```

- Get the `channel` by it's name

```js
const targetChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "Name of the channel");
```

#### If this is done you should have your `channel` now, but that's not all!

Now you want to check, if your bot really got the `channel` and if you want to be able to use `.join()`, you have to make sure it's a `VoiceChannel`:

```js
// Check if the channel is undefined or not
if(!targetChannel) return message.channel.send('Channel not found!');

// Check if the channel is a voice channel
if(targetChannel.type !== 'voice') return message.channel.send('This is not a voice channel!');

// If it passed the code above you can now let your bot join the channel
targetChannel.join().then(connection => {

    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    
    console.error(e);
```

Comment: the least you can do is reference the original author when you copy paste answers

Comment: @JoeMoore I did not copy paste that answer lol

Comment: I've seen that code all over this tag, I can find the original post if you would like? - edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844393/joining-a-voice-channel-on-ready-discord-js

Comment: @JoeMoore Ah you mean the last few lines, right, I have copied that a while ago in my bot and have now used it here. Did not remember that was from this question

Comment: no worries, just thought I should probably point it out

Answer (score 0):

You may store the variable as anything, as ID is a set of integers it can be stored without `quotes` **("")** , `template literals` **(``)**, etc. 
Although since it may conflict upon using methods such as `parseInt()` we would store it as a string. So let's say we have an ID now and we store it as:

```js
const Channel = ('ChannelID');
var Channel = ('ChannelID');
let Channel = ('ChannelID'); // of course only one of these
```

Where `ChannelID` is the actual ID, now we may access it later to fetch/get the channel like so:

```js
<client>.channels.cache.get(Channel) || <client>.channels.fetch(Channel);
```