# Discord.js 13 channel.join is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

I recently installed Discord.js 13.1.0 and my music commands broke because, apparently, `channel.join();` is not a function, although I have been using it for months on 12.5.3...

Does anybody know a fix for this?

Some parts of my join command:

```js
const { channel } = message.member.voice;
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

await channel.join();
```

It results in the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Discord.js no longer supports voice. You need to use the other package they made ([@discordjs/voice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/voice)). You can import `joinVoiceChannel` from there.

```js
//discord.js and client declaration
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.content === '!join') {
        joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
    }
})
```