# Not joining member's voice channel - DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make the bot join the channel the user is in.

But I get this error:

> TypeError: voiceChannel.join is not a function

I have tried changing `message.member.voice.channel` to `message.member.voiceChannel`. That did not work either. I am not sure what to do now.

The code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'],
    description: 'YT music commands',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to join a voice channel to use this command.');
        
        if(cmd === 'play'){
            //Boring music bot searching song in YouTube stuff
    
                try{
                    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
                    queueConstructor.connection = connection;
                    
                } catch(err){
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send("There was an error connecting to voice channel.");
                    throw err;
                }
            } 
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js 13 channel.join is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784950/discord-js-13-channel-join-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Installed that package and it says the module is not found.

Comment: How do you try to install it?

Comment: I installed the discordjs/voice package using npm. I've also added ```const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discord.js/voice');```. It says module not found.

Comment: What did you type in the console?

Comment: npm i @discordjs/voice

Comment: I went through the documentation of discord.js in GitHub. I see joinVoiceChannel() function there. And its usage being client.joinVoiceChannel(). But for me, it says joinVoiceChannel() is not a function.

Comment: Okay. I figured out how to make it join using the solution in the link you shared. But I have to figure out how to assign that to the "connection" const.