# song_queue.connection.play is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is the problem: when i'm running this code I get a error saying: `song_queue.connection.play is not a function`. The bot joins the voicechat correctly but the error comes when it tries to play a song. Sorry for the large amount of code but I really want to fix this so my bot can work. I got the code from a YouTube tutorial recorded in discord.js 12.4.1 (my version is the latest 13.1.0) and I think the error has to do with `@discordjs/voice`. I would **really** appreciate **any** help with getting this to work.

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const queue = new Map();
// queue (message.guild.id, queue_constructor object { voice channel, text channel, connection, song[]});
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'],
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord){
        
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to do that');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to do that');

        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if (cmd === 'play') {
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument');
            let song = {};

            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])){
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_title.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                //If the video is not a URL then use keywords to find that video.
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                    message.channel.send('Error finding your video');
                }
            }

            if (!server_queue){
                
                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }
    
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
    
                try {
                    const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                        guildId: message.guild.id,
                        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
                      })
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(`<:seelio:811951350660595772> **${song.title}** added to queue`);
            }
        }
    }
        }

    const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);
        
    if(!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 }).on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send('(`<:seelio:811951350660595772> Now Playing **${song.title}**`)')
}
```

Comment: Does this help at all? [Discord.js 13 channel.join is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784950/discord-js-13-channel-join-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discord.js V13 and @discordjs/voice

Since a relatively recent update to the Discord.js library a lot of things have changed in the way you play audio files or streams over your client in a Discord voice channel. There is a really useful guide by Discord to explain a lot of things to you on a base level [right here](https://discordjs.guide/), but I'm going to compress it down a bit and explain to you what is going wrong and how you can get it to work.

### Some prerequisites

It is important to note that for anything to do with voice channels for your bot it is necessary to have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent in your client. Without it your bot will not actually be able to connect to a voice channel even though it seems like it is. If you don't know what intents are yet, [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html) is the relevant page from the same guide.

Additionally you will need some extra libraries that will help you with processing and streaming audio files. These things will do a lot of stuff in the background that you do not need to worry about them, but without them playing any audio will not work. To find out what you need you can use the `generateDependecyReport()` function from *@discordjs/voice*. [Here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/#debugging-dependencies) is the page explaining how to use it and what dependencies you will need. To use the function you will have to import it from the *@discordjs/voice* library.

### Playing audio over a client

So once everything is set up you can get to how to play audio and music. You're already a great few steps on the way by using ytdl-core and getting a `stream` object from it, but audio is not played by using a `.play()` command on the connection. Instead you will need to utilize AudioPlayer and AudioResource objects.

##### AudioPlayer

The AudioPlayer is essentially your jukebox. You can make one by simply calling its function and storing that in a const like so:

```js
const player = createAudioPlayer()
```

This is a function from the *@discordjs/voice* library and will have to be imported just like `generateDependencyReport()`.
There are a few parameters you can give it to modify its behavior, but right now that is not important. You can read more about that on its page from the Discord guide right [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-player.html).

##### AudioResource

To get your AudioPlayer to actually play anything you will have to create an AudioResource. This is basically a version of your file or stream modified to work with the player. This is very simply done with another function from the *@discord.js/voice* library called `createAudioResource(...)`. This must once again be imported. As a parameter you can parse the location of an mp3 or webm file, but you can also use a stream object like you have already acquired. Just input `stream` as the parameter of that function.

To now play the resource there are two more steps. First you must subscribe your connection to the player. This basically tells the connection to broadcast whatever your AudioPlayer is playing. To do this simply call the `.subscribe()` function on your `connection` object with the player as a parameter like so:

```js
connection.subscribe(player)

player.play(resource)
```

The second line of code you see above is how you get your player to play your AudioResource. Just parse the resource as a parameter and it will start playing. You can find more on the AudioResource side of things on its page in the Discord guide right [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-resources.html).

This way takes a few more steps than it did in V12, but once you get the hang of this system it really isn't that bad or difficult.

### Leaving a voice channel

There is another thing that is going wrong in your code when you try to leave a voice channel. I can see that you did figure out how to join in V13 already, but .leave() unfortunately is no longer a valid function. Now, to leave a voice channel you must retrieve the `connection` object that you get from calling joinVoiceChannel(...) and call either .disconnect() or .destroy() on it. They are almost the same, but the latter also makes it so that you cannot use the connection again.

Comment: thank you! now my code works and I actually UNDERSTAND what i'm doing, it's good because now I will get better at coding, thank you again

Comment: @PinkTNT That's great! I'm glad I could help you. I'd hate to trouble you, but as it sounds like I was able to answer your question could I ask you to mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark to the top left of this post?

Comment: Of course, you did really answer my question so I clicked the check mark now

Comment: But may I ask you one more question?Where do I put my: .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    }); to get the queue to shift after the song ended?

Comment: Put it on your player, and 'finish' is not a state. The article I linked about AudioPlayers shows all the states in the life cycle. What you want to use is `'idle'` which is what it reaches when a resource has ended.