# voice_channel.join() is not a function in creating music bot for discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was coding a new music command for my discord bot and when I use `-play {url}`, I get an error. The error is: `voice_channel.join is not a function`.

I checked some websites including Stack Overflow but I did not find any useful solution. I want to update this code from discord.js v12 to discord.js v13. The code:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'], 
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(message,args, cmd, client, Discord){

        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');

        
        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        
        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};

            
            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
               
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }

            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }
                
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
    
                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(` **${song.title}** added to queue!`);
            }
        }

        else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if(cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);
    }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}

const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`There are no songs in queue `);
    }
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

const stop_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    server_queue.songs = [];
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}
```

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js 16.
vs code

Comment: Although you use `voice_channel` inside `queue_constructor`, you forgot to include what it is. So what is the `voice_channel` variable?

Comment: I edited my code, check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice support is moved to a new library in v13. You will need to install it by running `npm i @discordjs/voice` in your console.

Then, you can import the `joinVoiceChannel` method from it on the top of your file:

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
```

Once it's imported, you can replace `voice_channel.join()` with the following to [create a connection](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#creation):

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: voice_channel.id,
  guildId: voice_channel.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: voice_channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

Comment: I replaced your code and created a connection, but I'm getting an error for playing it:"
song_queue.connection.play is not a function, I added the following code
"

Comment: It's a pretty long answer, but it should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349776/song-queue-connection-play-is-not-a-function

Comment: i was reading this, but my english is weak, do you have a replacement code?

Comment: I'll try to rewrite it, but probably I only can do it in the morning.

Comment: I've just answered a post that has the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71653808/6126373

Comment: Hello, thank for always helping me. i ran into a new issue. i edited my code, so you may find the problem.

Comment: My answer solved the original issue and you should not just change your question once it's solved. It's pretty unfair to unaccept the answer that solved your original problem and change the question entirely. If you have a new issue, you can post it as a new question by adding more details. I'm usually happy to help.

Comment: ok, I asked a new question, i would be thankful if you answer that