# TypeError: connection.play is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this music bot project, I got it from YouTube and I added a little bit of my own things to it.

The problem is every time I send the `?play (songname)` command, it sends an error that `connection.play is not a function`. What should I do?

The error I get:

```
connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
           ^

TypeError: connection.play is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Pauli.Salminen\Desktop\DiscordBotPRojects\reactionroles\commands\play.js:41:24)       
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

This is my `play.js`:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  description: 'joins aadn plays muusic',
  async execute(kaoru, message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send('> **You need to join voicechannel first!**');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT'))
      return message.channel.send('> **You dont have right permissions!**');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK'))
      return message.channel.send('> **You dont have right permissions!**');
    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send('> **You need to insert name of the song!**');

    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: message.member.voice.channel,
      guildId: message.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

      return videoResult.videos.length > 1 ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    };

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
      connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 }).on('finish', () => {
        voiceChannel.leave();
      });

      await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now playing ***${video.title}***`);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('No video results found');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord.js, but, check the value of `connection` *before* calling `connection.play`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of changes in discord.js v13 where you have to use the `@discordjs/voice` module.

Your first mistake is that you don't provide an ID at `channelId: message.member.voice.channel`. The channel ID should be `message.member.voice.channel.id`.

Second, `play()` is no longer available on the `connection`. In v13, you have to create an audio player first, using the [`createAudioPlayer()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#createaudioplayer) method; then create an audio resource. Audio resources contain audio that can be played by an audio player to voice connections. To create one, you can use the [`createAudioResource()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#createaudioresource) method and pass your `stream` as the parameter.

Once the resource is created, you can play them on an audio player using [`player.play()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html#play). You also need to subscribe your `connection` to the `player` so the connection will broadcast whatever your `player` is playing. To do this, call the [`subscribe()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html#subscribe) method on your voice `connection` with the player as the parameter.

Also, there is no `connection.on` listener. You can use [`player.on`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html#on) though. To check if a song is finished, you can subscribe to the [`AudioPlayerStatus.Idle`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/enums/audioplayerstatus.html#idle) event.

And the last thing, to leave a channel, instead of `voiceChannel.leave()`, you should use either [`connection.disconnect()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html#disconnect) or [`connection.destroy()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html#destroy).

You can find the working code below:

```js
const {
  AudioPlayerStatus,
  createAudioPlayer,
  createAudioResource,
  joinVoiceChannel,
} = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  description: 'joins aadn plays muusic',
  async execute(kaoru, message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send('> **You need to join voicechannel first!**');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT'))
      return message.channel.send('> **You dont have right permissions!**');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK'))
      return message.channel.send('> **You dont have right permissions!**');
    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send('> **You need to insert name of the song!**');

    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
      guildId: message.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
      return videoResult.videos.length > 1 ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    };

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
      const player = createAudioPlayer();
      const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

      await player.play(resource);
      connection.subscribe(player);

      player.on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
      player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
        console.log(`song's finished`);
        connection.disconnect();
      });

      await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now playing ***${video.title}***`);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('No video results found');
    }
  },
};
```

PS: Make sure the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent is enabled. Without this, your bot will not be able to connect to a voice channel.