# channel.join() is not an function! Can anyone help me? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

it says channel.join() is not a function

```
 const guildId = '892147519063207996';

 const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("892164179186810881");
-->  channel.join();  <--
```

Comment: Are you using v13 or v12? Can you show rest of your code as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js 13 channel.join is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784950/discord-js-13-channel-join-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Since [discord.js v13](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/general/welcome), joining a channel has been changed a lot. First of all you will need a separate library called [`@discordjs/voice`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/voice). From this library you need the [`joinVoiceChannel()`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#joinvoicechannel) function which you can use like this:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
})
```

to join a voice channel. As long as the [`channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel) variable is a voice channel that bit of code will just work, no need to change anything about it.