# How can I install brew (or ffmpeg) on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, homebrew

As per the title, I'd like to know whether and how to install brew, because I need to install ffmpeg lib

I tried what it's written [here](http://linuxbrew.sh/):

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

test -d ~/.linuxbrew && PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "export PATH='$(brew --prefix)/bin:$(brew --prefix)/sbin'":'"$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH='$(brew --prefix)/bin:$(brew --prefix)/sbin'":'"$PATH"' >>~/.profile
```

but then brew is still not found:

```
bash: brew: command not found
```

Comment: Homebrew is for macOS. Heroku doesn't run macOS. You won't be able to use `brew` there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install FFMPEG on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011619/install-ffmpeg-on-heroku)

Comment: Actually there is a Linux version, which I've been able to install, but still I don't know how to install ffmpeg

Comment: Even if there is a Linux version (I have _no idea_ what its value would be considering the package managers that already exist for Linux) you probably shouldn't use it on Heroku. Heroku isn't a "regular" web host, or a VPS. You can't log on and install things interactively. You need to build them into your application slug. Have you read the duplicate question I linked?

Comment: I'm trying to follow that other post, I installed (heroku buildpacks:add) ffmpeg pack, but then I don't get how to use it within my app

Comment: ...your question was about installing ffmpeg. I assume you had a reason for doing that, but I have no idea what it is. You haven't told us anything about your application or shared any code.

Comment: Is `~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew` working?

Comment: I solved as suggested in the post linked here by Chris