# Trying to install FFMPEG on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg

I'm trying to host a Discord bot with music feature in Heroku, but when I play the music, it says "FFMPEG not found", so **I tried adding that buildpack: https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
but it gives the same error**, even if I restart the dynos. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install FFMPEG on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011619/install-ffmpeg-on-heroku)

Comment: try installing 'fluent' which works well on node/heroku   https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, Robert!