# How to deploy Node Media Server app on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io, pm2

I am trying to deploy a NodeJS live streaming server which works on heroku built on rtmp server using node-media-server and socket.io. I am facing issue in starting the node-media-server since it needs 2 ports to run as per config format:

```
const NodeMediaServer = require('node-media-server');


const config = {
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60
  },
  http: {
    port: 8000,
    allow_origin: '*'
  }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config)
nms.run();
```

I've tried deploying app on new heroku app by following official [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs). Since Heroku provides only one port per dyno, it gives me these logs on my heroku app dashboard:

```
2020-04-07T23:08:24.289041+00:00 app[web.1]: 4/7/2020 23:08:24 23 [ERROR] Node Media Trans Server startup failed. ffmpeg:/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg cannot be executed.
2020-04-07T23:08:24.290753+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-04-07T23:08:24.291397+00:00 app[web.1]: listening on port 19586
2020-04-07T23:08:24.292059+00:00 app[web.1]: 4/7/2020 23:08:24 23 [ERROR] Node Media Rtmp Server Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19586
2020-04-07T23:08:24.292694+00:00 app[web.1]: 4/7/2020 23:08:24 23 [ERROR] Node Media Http Server Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19586
2020-04-07T23:08:24.293383+00:00 app[web.1]: 4/7/2020 23:08:24 23 [ERROR] Node Media WebSocket Server Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19586
2020-04-07T23:08:24.682440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-07T23:08:24.693405+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to the database
```

I need to know how I can deploy my app on heroku (or any other alternative) to make it available in production mode. My server works fine on my MacBook Pro.
Here's my code:

```
const { NodeMediaServer } = require('node-media-server');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process')
const port = process.env.PORT||5000
const port2 = process.env.PORT||8000
const port3 = process.env.PORT||8001


const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('./app/controllers/socketIO')(io);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://databasecredentials",
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connected to the database');
    }
  }
);

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('socketio', io);
app.set('server', server);
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
  }
});

const nodeMediaServerConfig = {
  rtmp: {
    port: port2,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 60,
    ping_timeout: 30
  },
  http: {
    port: port3,
    mediaroot: './media',
    allow_origin: '*'
  },
  trans: {
    ffmpeg: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    tasks: [
      {
        app: 'live',
        ac: 'aac',
        mp4: true,
        mp4Flags: '[movflags=faststart]'
      }
    ]
  }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(nodeMediaServerConfig);
nms.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Heroku, but in the first line of the logs it states:

> [ERROR] Node Media Trans Server startup failed. ffmpeg:/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg cannot be executed.

you need to install `ffmpeg` on the machine running the code. This is the first step to get your server starting (this might not fix all the problems you're having but this is the first thing you need to start with).
 I'm trying to do something similar using GCP. In order to get it to run, I created a package.json file and set the start script to `apt install --fix-missing --assume-yes ffmpeg && node app.js` as a temporary workaround:

```
{
    "name": "app-service-hello-world",
    "description": "Simple Hello World Node.js sample for Azure App Service",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": "Microsoft",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "apt install --fix-missing --assume-yes ffmpeg && node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-media-server": "^2.1.9"
    }
}
```

This might help you adding ffmpeg correctly to your Heroku environment: [Install FFMPEG on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011619/install-ffmpeg-on-heroku)