# discord ffprobe / avprobe and ffmpeg / avconv not found error

Tags: python, github, heroku, bots, discord

I want to add my discord bot to **Heroku** hosting via **Github** and in **Github** I added everything I need.

A `requirements.txt` text document that has all the necessary Python libraries for my bot as well-Procfile in which info to run my bot

And text `document-runtime.txt` in which information about my Python version is **3.6.7** (I only put this version because `discord.py` is not available on Python version higher than **3.6**) and, accordingly, the file with code.

But there is a function in my bot listening to music is when the user enters the voice channel registers accordingly Leica Geosystems introduces the link above command and it will be music Media player and all I have done it with the help of `youtube_dl` library and `ffmpeg` installed.

But when I downloaded and started to Use the bot to listen to music, heroku gave me this error:

> - Traceback (most recent call last):
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244630 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py" , line 892, in invoke
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244630 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke (ctx)
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244632 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py" , line 797, in invoke
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244633 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: await injected (* ctx.args, ** ctx.kwargs)
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244660 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py" , line 92, in wrapped
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244660 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError (exc) from exc
>     2020-05-18T06: 08: 04.244704 + 00: 00 app [worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe / avprobe and ffmpeg / avconv not found. Please install one. well, or if it's easier - discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe / avprobe and ffmpeg / avconv not found. Please install one.

Please explain in detail what needs to be done and how to make the function with music work

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011619/install-ffmpeg-on-heroku).

Answer (score 2):

so what you need to do is that you need to go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps//settings or go to settings in the heroku and scroll down to buildpack. Then you need to copy the link given below and paste it in that section

Link:
https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git